# I am trying to open Nova and getting directories instead of welcome page

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have set-up a Laravel-Nova project. And when i try to open this URL (htttps://localhost/81/App/nova) it opens up this folders directory instead of opening nova/login page.
[image]
 I have followed all the instructions but still it's not getting resolved.

I have tried looking for solution of it but didn't find anything.

Comment: What directory are you serving as the root location in Apache? It should be /public but looks like you have it 1 level higher.

Comment: You can access `https://localhost/81/App/public/nova/login` but you will not get everything work as expected, like you will miss css in page. so better use `localhost:8000/nova/login`.

Comment: I got resolved issue by running `php artisan serve` which serve us `http://127.0.0.1:8000/nova` to run the project successfully. THANKS!

Comment: The real fix here is to adjust your Apache configuration's `DocumentRoot` to point at the `public` directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `php artisan serve` in your Terminal and then go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/nova` or any link which is getting generated by your terminal. THANKS!

Comment: This works for local development, but you should **never** use `php artisan serve` in production.

Comment: @ceejayoz can you explain not why? Running guzzle for Laravel passport requires it be served correct?

Comment: @Salman Read the red box and documentation on https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php (which is what `php artisan serve` uses). Guzzle and Passport work fine on a regular production-ready webserver.